# HTML view page save as PDF using roatativa

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rotativa

I have following image for the **Create_Brochure** ActionResult in Brochure **Contrller** Class

[image]

Here the whole URL of that Action

***http://localhost:49669/Brochure/Create_Brochure?%5B0%5D.Property_ID=1&%5B0%5D.IsChecked=true&%5B0%5D.IsChecked=false&%5B1%5D.Property_ID=2&%5B1%5D.IsChecked=true&%5B1%5D.IsChecked=false&%5B2%5D.Property_ID=3&%5B2%5D.IsChecked=true&%5B2%5D.IsChecked=false&%5B3%5D.Property_ID=4&%5B3%5D.IsChecked=false&%5B4%5D.Property_ID=5&%5B4%5D.IsChecked=false&%5B5%5D.Property_ID=6&%5B5%5D.IsChecked=false&%5B6%5D.Property_ID=7&%5B6%5D.IsChecked=false&%5B7%5D.Property_ID=8&%5B7%5D.IsChecked=false&%5B8%5D.Property_ID=9&%5B8%5D.IsChecked=false&%5B9%5D.Property_ID=10&%5B9%5D.IsChecked=false***

Once I click I want to save this view page as PDF , to do that I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/818197/Generate-PDF-in-ASP-NET-MVC-Using-Rotativa)

So this is the cshtml view page , so it doesn't have a model class

```
@model IEnumerable<int>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Template";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Create a Template</title>
</head>
<body>



                <div style="width:100%; padding:10px; float:left;">


                    <table width=1100 cellpadding=10>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <div id="topper" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';background-color: black;color: white;clear: both;text-align: center;padding: 5px;border-radius:15px 15px 0px 0px;">
                                    Bank Brochure
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                       @if (Model.Contains(1))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <div id="header" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';background-color: slategray; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 5px;">
                                        <h1 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; color: black; text-align: center;" contentEditable='True'>Product Name</h1>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }

                        @if (Model.Contains(2))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" style="background-color:lightgrey">
                                    <div id="header" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';color: white; text-align: center; padding: 5px;border-radius">
                                        <h2 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; color: black;float:left" contentEditable='True'>Product Description</h2>
                                        <p  style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; color: black;float:left" contentEditable='True'>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.Standing on the River Thames London has been a major settlement for two millennia, its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }

                        @if (Model.Contains(3))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                    <div id="header" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';background-color: steelblue; color: white; text-align: center; padding: 5px;">
                                        <h3 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI'; color: white; text-align: center;font-style:italic" contentEditable='True'>"Unique Selling Propositions It enables ASP.NET Web developers to replace any textbox with an intuitive Word-like WYSIWYG html editor.
"</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }

                        @if()....

                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <div id="footer" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';background-color: black;color: white;clear: both;text-align: center;padding: 5px;border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px;">
                                    Copyright © 2015 Zoo Group , Solution by kelum.
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>

    <br />
    <button id="btn_sumbit" type="button" class="btn btn-danger submit">Save as PDF</button>
</body>
</html>

@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btn_sumbit').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("DownloadActionAsPDF", "Brochure")',
                dataType: "text",
                data: null,
                success: function (data) {

                },
                error: console.log("it did not work"),
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

this is controller class method to save to PDF

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadActionAsPDF()
    {
        string path = Request.Url.ToString();
        //Request.Url.ToString() using to get current page URL
        return new Rotativa.UrlAsPdf(path) { FileName = "UrlTest.pdf" };
    }
```

but once I click this button it doesn't save to PDF file,

Comment: Do you get any Error?? what happen when you debug??

Comment: nope, none of error occurring, once I debug its triggering `DownloadActionAsPDF()` method , and its compiling smoothly , but no PDF file generating

Comment: If a understand correctly your requirement is to save the PDF directly..

Comment: yes , it is,as I feel this DownloadActionAsPDF() method is the problem here

Comment: Didn't you see any logs in browser console  `it did not work`

Comment: This will Not work because what you are doing is Calling the same method again and again.. `path` has the url of `DownloadActionAsPDF`

Comment: just check have you imported namespace for rotativa

Answer (score 2):

As i already commented that your code is calling the same Method again and again..

You can do the same thing by using `ActionAsPdf` and point it to the **Create_Brochure** Action method of yours

Ex:-

```
    public ActionResult DownloadActionAsPDF()
            {
              return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("Create_Brochure") { FileName = "TestPdf.pdf"};
            }


    public ActionResult Create_Brochure()
            {
               //Your logic....
               return View()  
            }
```

and in your view page no need of a button or a `Ajax` call can be done by a `anchor tag`

View:-

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("DownloadActionAsPDF", "MyDiary")" class="btn btn-danger submit" download>SaveAsPdf</a>
```